# Is it possible to use AES encrypted in a static MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, static, aes

I have a table that is performing quite slowly. I would like to adjust the structure of the table so that the format is static. However, I have a field that is using AES encryption. Is there a static field type I can use to store AES encrypted data?

Edit:

Here is more information on Static Fixed-Length Table Characteristics in case needed:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/static-format.html

Comment: What do you mean by "format is static"? Do you assume that tables with fixed row length perform better? That's not true.

Comment: What do you mean by a table that is performing slowly? Do you mean a _query_ against that table is performing slowly? You haven't mentioned any specific query.

Comment: In my experience, static tables run faster. This is from the official MySQL documentation: "[Static] is also the fastest of the on-disk formats due to the ease with which rows in the data file can be found on disk: To look up a row based on a row number in the index, multiply the row number by the row length to calculate the row position. Also, when scanning a table, it is very easy to read a constant number of rows with each disk read operation."

Comment: Are you using InnoDB or MyISAM tables? That documentation applies only to MyISAM. The [downsides of using MyISAM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148/myisam-versus-innodb/17706717#17706717) are enough that I would recommend never to use them.

Comment: (Terminology question) Please provide a link to the discussion of "static" in MySQL.

Comment: I think the excerpt is found in this page, which does use the "static" terminology for a fixed-length MyISAM row: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/static-format.html